# OpenSSL error while loading CRLnumber

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, crl

I am unable to generate a CRL. I am probably missing something in the  configuration file. The error I get is "openssl error while loading crl number."
Crl config section:

```ini
[ CA_default ]
# Directory and file locations.
dir               = box/ca
certs             = $dir/certs
crl_dir           = $dir/crl
new_certs_dir     = $dir/newcerts
database          = $dir/index.txt
serial            = $dir/serial
RANDFILE          = $dir/private/.rand
# For certificate revocation lists.
crlnumber         = $dir/crlnumber
crl               = $dir/crl/RcCA.crl
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 30
```

The command I use:

```
openssl ca -config full-path-to-openssl.cnf  -gencrl -out full-path-to-RcCA.crl
```

Where rcCA is the crl file.
File structure: 
root CA

- certs
- crl
- csr
- intermediate
- newcerts
- pfx
- private
- serial
- openssl.cnf
- index.txt
- crlnumber

Bottom three are files, above are folders. 
The answers I've found are pointing to the lack of index file. But it exists on my machine. I don't know if I put it in the right place.

#### Edit:

@StacksOfZtuff helped. But now I am getting different errors. I don't know if this is considered resolved or I am just masking the previous error.

`22048:error:2207707B:X509 V3 routines:V2I_AUTHORITY_KEYID:unable to get issuer keyid:.\crypto\x509v3\v3_akey.c:165:`

`22048:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:.\crypto\x509v3\v3_conf.c:95:name=authorityKeyIdentifier, value=keyid:always`

#### Edit to second comment:

I would like to emphasize, my CA is working properly, except for the CRL issue. I am able to generate key,csr, cer and pkcs12. I seem to be able to add entries to the CRL, but when I try to call the `gencrl` command, I get errors. I am not even sure if it matters

#### See also

Follow-up post: https://serverfault.com/questions/829608/openssl-generate-crl-yields-the-error-unable-to-get-issuer-keyiid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Initialize crlnumber file first

Try this:

```
echo 1000 > crlnumber
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it generates a different error. So i don't know if I should consider it resolved..:

Comment: @Moutabreath: Here's a bare-bones proof of concept shell script, that will generate a CA that can issue CRLs. (Not much else will work, though.) [`Make-new-OpenSSL-PoC-CA.sh`](http://pastebin.com/SHX0EDWR) Deployment info [here](http://pastebin.com/3pRyY3Ft).

Comment: I tried putting the values 0 and 1 in crlnumber, but they are not deemed valid values (the error is the same). I wonder why.

Comment: @MatteoSteccolini: It's more about the number format than the absolute value. For 0 and 1, there has to be a leading 0, so "00" or "01" do work.

Comment: I don't know where in the documentation this is stated, I stumbled upon the same error and could not figure out why it was not working.

Comment: @F30+ it doesn't need a leading zero as such, but it **must be an _even_ number of _hex_ digits**; each hex pair is one byte in the resulting ASN1 INTEGER. The same is true of the `serial` file for certs, and for that case the man page gives an example of `01` (i.e. an even number of digits for the numeric value 1) but without explaining exactly why.