# How can I add a CRL to an existing Certificate Authority Certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, dovecot, certificate-authority

We have our own CA for internal use that secures about ten servers/services. We don't actually have or need a Certificate Revocation List.

But, as we are attempting to setup Dovecot to verify the identity of our Postfix server, we have discovered that Dovecot will not accept our CA certificate unless it has a CRL attached to the same file.

If we have a public CA cert, `authority.crt`, can we add some dummy CRL data on to that authority certificate file to make Dovecot happy?

**UPDATE:**

I think I have this almost figured out:

```
openssl ca -config ca/authority.cnf \
-gencrl -crldays 365 -crl_hold holdInstructionCallIssuer
```

But I get:

```
unable to load number from ssl/crlnumber
error while loading CRL number
140581396727104:error:0D066096:asn1 encoding routines:a2i_ASN1_INTEGER:short line:../crypto/asn1/f_int.c:140:
```

The `crlnumber` file didn't exist. I tried to `touch` it into existence, which didn't work, and then I added the number `1` to the top, which also didn't work. I probably need to set somthing up in the `authority.cnf` configuration file for the `crlnumber` file.

Comment: Are you following [this](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/#id10) article?  You will need to see if your CA software will generate a CRL, and if so, create one purely for the purpose of attaching it to the file.  The only valid _dummy_ CRL would be one generated by the CA as it has to be signed by the CA's private key.

Comment: @garethTheRed: Yes, that's where I found "The CRLs are required to exist.". Can I generate an empty CRL, sign it with the CA key, then append it to a certificate file? If so, how?

Comment: To answer that, you would need to read the documentation for your CA.  If you haven't revoked any certificate, then the CRL will be empty.

Comment: Procedure for creating a dummy CRL file here.  
`openssl ca -config ca.conf -gencrl -keyfile ca.key -cert ca.crt -out root.crl.pem`

`openssl crl -inform PEM -in root.crl.pem -outform DER -out root.crl`

https://blog.didierstevens.com/2013/05/08/howto-make-your-own-cert-and-revocation-list-with-openssl/

Comment: Dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/823679/openssl-error-while-loading-crlnumber (and the answer is that the `crlnumber` file must contain an even number of hex digits, but not absurdly large)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to make a CRL is:

```
openssl ca -config ca/authority.cnf \
-gencrl -crldays 365 -crl_hold holdInstructionCallIssuer
```

In `authority.cnf`, you need to have:

```
[ CA_default ]
crlnumber         = $dir/ca/crlnumber
crl               = $dir/ca/crl/ca.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 365
```

You also need to create the `crlnumber` file in advance and populate it with a number. The number must be an even number of digits. ie `1` is not valid, but `01` is valid.

You'll get a CRL that can be pasted into the authority's crt file after the certificate. And Dovecot accepts that.